# VSCode breakpoints unbound when debugging a React app in a docker container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

I'm having issues debugging with VSCode a React app created with [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) and running in a Docker container.

The app runs fine with `docker compose up` and it correctly stops its execution until I attach with the debugger.
[image: Debugger attached and on hold at the first line, the breakpoint at the following line is active]

However, after that, only breakpoints in the `start.js` file behave correctly, while any other breakpoint in my source files stays unbound.
[image: Other breakpoints appear hollow and do not work]

### Project Setup

**package.json**

I defined a new script `start:debug` to run the application in inspect mode.

```json
    {
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.8.1",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.4.2",
        "@mui/material": "^5.4.3",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "axios": "^0.26.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "start:debug": "react-scripts --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    ...
    }
```

**Dockerfile**

```bash
FROM node:16-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

# Run app
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:debug" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: test
    container_name: test
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app/src
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.node
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "9229:9229"
```

**.vscode/launch.json**

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "restart": true,
            "port": 9229,
            "address": "localhost",
            "trace": true,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app",
            "sourceMaps": true
        },
    ]
}
```

---

I tried every configuration I could find but I did not manage to make it work. Could anyone help me spot where the issue is?

---

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a web-based react app - you will need to run a web browser to debug it. Here is a setup that I did:

1. set up a docker container for React with bind-mounts to my main system
2. enter container from terminal `docker exec -ti react-ptc /bin/bash`
3. create react app inside container in /app directory
4. cd into app directory
5. run `npm run eject` - required to manage webpack config later
6. run `npm run start` inside docker container
7. open react project folder with vscode from bind mount on host system.

Number 7 is necessary because otherwise VSCode will not be able to launch a web browser for debugging. Watch your permissions though. You may need to set bind mounted `/react` directory to host user permissions.

Here is part of `docker-compose.yml` I used:

```
version: '3'
services:
  react-ptc:
    image: 'dmitryr117/node:18.8.0-dev'
    container_name: react-ptc
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./react:/app
    environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
      - PORT=80
      - WDS_SOCKET_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0
    expose:
      - 80
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

I am however running my system with an `nginx` reverse proxy and using `/etc/hosts` to emulate real domain name behaviour on local environment.

Now for `launch.json` and `webpack.config.js`

launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Brave Debug",
      "url": "http://client.ptc.test", // can set to http://localhost:8080
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "timeout": 20000,
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "runtimeExecutable": "/snap/bin/brave", // I am on Ubuntu using Brave web browser
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--new-window",
        "--incognito",
        "--user-data-dir=${workspaceFolder}/chrome-profiles/ReactProfile",
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
      ],
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        // requires inline-source-map in webpack.config.js for devtool
        // "browser-path": "web-root path"
        // IMPORTANT AREA:
        // Check sources in web browser DeveloperTools and change /app/ptc to 
        // your path above /src directory
        "/app/ptc/*": "${webRoot}/*",
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

In  previously ejected `config` directory look for `webpack.config.js` and update as wollows:

```
    ...
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    // isEnvProduction
    //   ? shouldUseSourceMap
    //     ? 'source-map'
    //     : false
    //   : isEnvDevelopment && 'cheap-module-source-map',
    // These are the "entry points" to our application.
    // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
    ...
```

That's it. Also update your `.gitignore` to avoid committing browser profile:

```
...
# browser_profile
/chrome-profiles
```

Should work from here. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for a solution that did not require ejecting CRA... After all I can successfully attach with the debugger!

Comment: I think the problem is that you have to set `devtool: 'inline-source-map'` somehow. Maybe there is a way to do it using environment variables, but I didn't dig that deep so I'm not sure.

Comment: Hey, thank you! I had a problem with docker and debug. To the original lanch.json I had to add only `sourceMapPathOverrides:{"/app/*": "${webRoot}/*"}` and everything works fine.